# Using ASP.NET Trying to access a file server and load files into a file tree on web site

Tags: asp.net

I am using ASP.NET, a newbie to it too, and I am trying to access a folder on a file server and view the files contained in the folder in a file tree within a web site on a different server. I can http to the folder but when I try to connect using a direct path to the file server I get nothing, no errors pop, just no show. What am I doing wrong or is there other issues I don't know about? Here is a link that is working but when I use it to go to the file server nothing...
 public const string InterestPenalty = @"D:\Charts\Clayton\Interest Penalty";

My link...
 public const string InterestPenalty = @"\cfofileserver\Projects\files";

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
//get root directory

DirectoryInfo rootDir = new DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath("~path"));

//create and add the root node to the tree view
TreeNode rootNode = new TreeNode(rootDir.Name, rootDir.FullName);

TreeView1.Nodes.Add(rootNode);

//begin recursively traversing the directory structure
TraverseTree(rootDir, rootNode);


private void TraverseTree(DirectoryInfo currentDir, TreeNode currentNode)

{
    //loop through each sub-directory in the current one
    foreach (DirectoryInfo dir in currentDir.GetDirectories())
    {
        //create node and add to the tree view
        TreeNode node = new TreeNode(dir.Name, dir.FullName);
        currentNode.ChildNodes.Add(node);
        //recursively call same method to go down the next level of the tree
        TraverseTree(dir, node);
    }
    //loop through each sub-directory in the current one
    foreach (FileInfo file in currentDir.GetFiles())
    {
        //create node and add to the tree view
        TreeNode node = new TreeNode(file.Name, file.FullName);
        currentNode.ChildNodes.Add(node);
    }

}
```